# Suffix Length in Lucene Fuzzy Search

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I have been using lucene for building indexes of documents, and performing search on them. I know that lucene supports FuzzyQuery, which is based on levenshtein distance.

FuzzyQuery also has an option to define prefix length, where we can keep the first few characters of search term fixed. I want to know whether there is an option to define suffix length. Or please suggest some implementation where I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for the prefix in `FuzzyQuery`, is that it allows the search to narrow the possible result set before checking for fuzzy matches, and so provides a significant performance improvement.  Adding a suffix doesn't provide any such benefit.

The best way to achieve this and reap to performance benefit may be to index the tokens reversed, by adding a [`ReverseStringFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/reverse/ReverseStringFilter.html) into your analyzer.  This is similarly often used to support leading wildcard queries without the big performance hit that typically comes with them.

Comment: Wouldn't adding a fixed suffix length reduce the result set in a symmetric manner? My usecase is such that I want the last few characters of a field to match exactly, while tolerating some fuzzy match in the first few characters. I think combining ReverseStringFilter and Prefix Length will help me achieve this. Keeping this open to see if someone suggests a more elegant way.

Comment: @Ulrich - The suffix isn't an effective way to reduce the result set size performantly.  Think of the lucene index as the index of a book.  Knowing the first couple of letters allows you to flip right to the correct part of the index and find a block of words that you need to look at.  If you know that last couple letters of the word, you still have scan through every word in the index to find the right words.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. I was under the impression that we can fix any given characters, and make the search space smaller.